# Xcode 11 beta 4 error: Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode11

I've downloaded the latest Xcode beta 4. When I build I'm getting the same error with 3 of my pods:

```
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-w'
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-Xanalyzer'
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-analyzer-disable-all-checks'
```

This is the MarqueeLabel pod logs:
[image]

I have tried:

- Cleaning and deep cleaning (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>)
- Deleting the Derived Data folder
- Restarting Xcode

I can't see the error listed in the release notes. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes

Does anyone know what the problem is or a workaround?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a known issue with Cocoapods and Xcode 11 Beta 4 where [`inhibit_all_warnings!` causes arguments to be set for Swift which do not compile](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9013). Removing this inhibit resolves the issue, and Swift warnings can be inhibited with `SWIFT_SUPPRESS_WARNINGS = YES` on targets instead.

Comment: The `inhibit_all_warnings!` issue was fixed in CocoaPods 1.7.5, but there are other issues introduced by Xcode 11 beta 4 regarding pods with a podspec that specifies a `compiler_flags`.

Answer (score 20):

[CocoaPods had a fix for this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/9014) that got released as part of **CocoaPods 1.7.5**.

---

*Below is the answer preceding the 1.7.5 release:*

<sub>If you need to use Xcode 11 Beta 4 in the mean time, you could install a patched version of CocoaPods from that pull request:</sub>

<sub>1. Open Gemfile, replace `gem 'cocoapods'` with</sub>

```
gem 'cocoapods', :git => 'https://github.com/dnkoutso/CocoaPods.git', :branch => "swift_compiler_warnings"
```

<sub>2. Run `bundle install` and `bundle exec pod install`</sub>

<sub>Keep in mind, this is a temporary solution.</sub>

Comment: I can't upvote this enough!  Thanks for the timely info, Xcode beta 4 was only released yesterday!

Comment: FYI, the cocoapods PR for this feature is [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/9014).

Comment: Thanks for the link, @JordanWood. I edited pingwinator's answer to include a link to the PR as well.

Comment: It looks like this fix has now been shipped in version 1.7.5, so updating Cocoapods should resolve the issue.

Comment: for me <unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-w' still exist

Comment: @RomanS it's under discussion since yesterday on the pull request itself.

Answer (score 7):

The latest version of CocoaPods (1.7.5) has this issue fixed!

1. In Terminal run

   `sudo gem update cocoapods`
2. And then, on your project directory

   `pod install`

Comment: <unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-w' still exist

Comment: Any thoughts as to why this might not be working? I created a new iOS project, pod init, add Down as a pod, pod install, and it fails. Verified on 1.7.5.

Comment: Looks like the Down pod is having issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089656/xcode-11-beta-4-build-error-command-compileswiftsources-failed-with-a-nonzero

Answer (score -1):

Resolved for me!!!!

The issue is actually i created two files with same name. So after i renamed one of a file and error cleared.